JPA how to add a join chain on one Entity?
class A{
@ID
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="bid",referencedColumnName="id")
private B b;
}

class B{
@ID
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cid", referencedColumnName="id")
private C c;
}

class C{
@ID
private Long id;
}

interface ARepo{
@Query("select a from A a where 1=1")
List<A> findAllA()
}

I want to execute findAllA()to get All A with B and C，but there is a error like :
java.lang.ClassCastException: entity.C cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

so what is the problem?
if this is not reachable, what can i do to achieve this:
select a.*, b.*, c.* from a left join b on a.bid = b.id left join c on b.cid = c.id where 1=1


I think in your case you should write a CriteriaQuery for flexibility. However if you wish to go ahead with query approach, please give a try using JOIN FETCH, something similar to @Query("select a from A a join fetch a.b b join fetch b.c")

I've tried this, but there is the same exception.

Try adding FetchType.LAZY.
Since you are getting java.lang.ClassCastException: entity.C cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable can you try debugging by implementing Serializable in all 3 entities if this works?

I've resolved the problem by implements Serializable:
class A{
@ID
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="bid",referencedColumnName="id")
private B b;
}

class B implements Serializable{
@ID
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="cid", referencedColumnName="id")
private C c;
}

class C implements Serializable {
@ID
private Long id;
}

interface ARepo{
@Query("select a from A a where 1=1")
List<A> findAllA()
}

thank u guys!
